# Laravel Forget password link is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel , and am trying to implement forget password in my project. I am receiving forget password Email , but when i clicked in it, it shows `object not found` error . Following is my code in routes

```
Route::get('user/password/reset', 'User\UserAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('user/password/email', 'User\UserAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.reequest');
Route::post('user/password/reset', 'User\UserAuth\ResetPassswordController@reset')->name('password.email');
Route::get('/password/reset/{token?}', 'User\UserAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
```

Following is the code in ForgetPasswordController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User\UserAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use JsValidator;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    protected $validationRules = [
                                        'email' => 'required|email',
                                    ];

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->validationRules,[],[],'#forgotform');
        return view('user.auth.passwords.email')->with(['validator' => $validator]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('users');
    }
}
```

Following is the cod in ResetPaawordcontroller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User\UserAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use JsValidator;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $redirectTo = '/user/home';

    protected $validationRules = [
                                        'name' => 'required|max:255',
                                        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
                                        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
                                    ];


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('user.guest');
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        echo "hi";
        die();
        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->validationRules,[],[],'#resetform');
        return view('user.auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email, 'validator' => $validator]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('users');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('user');
    }
}
```

When i clicked on `Reset Password` button , reset password form is not showing , it shows object not found error

What is the problem here?

I have uploaded my error screenshot[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please paste the error message(s).

Comment: Object Not Found   This is the error message

Comment: You should paste more than just "Object not found". Which object is not found? Can you show us the stacktrace. Only that way we can try to help. Please add this to your question!

Comment: Updated error message screnshot

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using ? in the latest one, you'll need tu use the laravel/ui package, which is no longer integrated in laravel (but is now set as a package). And btw, you should set a single line to deal with route (this line will depends on your laravel project version)

Comment: Can you show that for me